# How to assign sets of numbers from a text file to sets of variables in C++ depending on the function's argument?

Tags: c++, function, file, io

I need to assign sets of numbers from a text file to a set of variables. The function's parameter is meant to decide which line should be assigned to variables. The text file looks like this:

3 6 8 10

2 4 8 10

3 5 7 10

So for example if I call GetEx(2) I want it to set variables to: var1 = 2, var2 = 4, var3 = 8, var4 = 10 and I need to be able to use them further in the code, outside the function, which I'm not yet sure how to do. For now the function has cout at the end just for testing. Currently it always assigns the last line to the variables. Any advice would be appreciated. Function:

```
void GetEx(int o)
{
    ifstream inputFile("ex.txt");
    string line;
    int var1, var2, var3, var4;
    for (int l = 0; l < o; l++)
    {
        while (getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            istringstream ss(line);
            ss >> var1 >> var2 >> var3 >> var4;

        }
    }
    cout << var1 << var2 << var3 << var4 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `struct`.

Comment: Sounds like an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), to me. Your indexing starts at zero (`for (int l = 0; ...);`) so your lines are indexed 0: (3, 6, 8, 10), 1: (2, 4, 8, 10), 2: (3, 5, 7, 10). You may find that you get the correct behaviour with either `for (int l = 1; l < o; ++l)` or `for int l = 0; l < o - 1; ++l)`. Or, of course, simply using zero-based indexing for `o` as well as for `l`. Also, that you don't need to parse each line into the var1..var4 variables; you can loop over `getline` for `o` iterations, then stream into var1..var4 once at the end.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the response, I tried changing the for loop to what you suggested, but then I get a "Run-time check failure, variable var4 is being used without being initialised" for all 4 variables. Also if it was an off-by-one error wouldn't at least one of the parameters give different results? And for the latter part of your response, how exactly could I do that? I am still unsure how the 'while (getline(inputFile, line))' loop works since I found that part somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int Var1;
    int Var2;
    int Var3;
    int Var4;
};

//Returns false if file failed to open, not enough lines in file or wrong format.
bool GetEx(int o, MyStruct& Result)     
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("date.txt");
    if (!inputFile.is_open())
        return false;

    std::string line;
    int i = 1;
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        if (i == o)
        {
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            ss >> Result.Var1 >> Result.Var2 >> Result.Var3 >> Result.Var4;
            if (ss)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Format failure.
                return false;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }

    //Not enough lines in file.
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    const int LineNumber = 2;  //Line number to read.

    MyStruct Result;
    if (!GetEx(LineNumber, Result))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file,file has less then " << LineNumber << " lines or wrong format.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << Result.Var1 << " " << Result.Var2 << " " << Result.Var3 << " " << Result.Var4 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I see my search skills could use some honing, next time I'll try looking even harder.